# Why are spoken and written English so different?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, linguistics

This is in some way a question regarding the evolution of the English language: why did it happen that, more than any alphabetic lamguage that I know of, English language has developed such independent and pronouncing norms?

It depends on the different etymology of the words English has adopted, but it's clearly not only that, because every language includes words from many different sources. It goes down to the core of the language itself, I believe, because very basic English words show this problematic behaviour, like those including the letters "gh".

I don't think it's about its spread around the world either, because every language shows dialects, some more different than others; some dialects even have different alphabets than the relative official language, but I don't see the same phenomenon of divergence of written and spoken word as occurs in English.

From what you know, is there any known explanation?

Comment: @Decapitated Soul Good catch.